# Setting values of dynamically added input fields changing all input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where users can create recipes. I start them off with one ingredient field (among others) and then use .append() to add as many more as they want to the div container that holds the first ingredient.  The first input field has an id of IngredientName1 and dynamically added input fields are IngredientName2, IngredientName3, etc.

When they start typing in the input field, I pop a list of available ingredients filtered by the value they key into IngredientNameX.  When they click on an ingredient in the list, it sets the value of the IngredientNameX field to the text from the div - like a search & click to complete thing.  This all works very well; however, when you add IngredientName2 (or any beyond the one I started them with initially) clicking on an available ingredient sets the values of every single IngredientNameX field.  No matter how many there are.

I hope this is enough context without being overly verbose, here's my code (I've removed a lot that is not relevant for the purpose of posting, hoping I didn't remove too much):

```html
<div id="ingredientsContainer">
    <input type="hidden" id="ingredientCounter" value="1">
        <div class="ingredientsRowContainer">
            <div class="ingredientsInputContainer"><input class="effect-1 ingredientsInput" type="text" name="IngredientName1" placeholder="Ingredient" id="IngredientName1" data-ingID="1"><span class="focus-border"></span></div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="Ingredient1ID" id="Ingredient1ID">
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('keyup', "[id^=IngredientName]",function () {            
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            var searchValue = $(this).val();
            var valueLength = value.length;
            if(valueLength>1){
                var theIngredient = $(this).attr("data-ingID");
                $("#Ingredients").removeClass("hidden")
                var $results = $('#Ingredients').children().filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text() === searchValue;
                });
                //user selected an ingredient from the list
                $(".ingredientsValues").click(function(){
                    console.log("theIngredient: "+theIngredient);//LOGS THE CORRECT NUMBER
                    var selectedIngredientID = $(this).attr("id");
                    var selectedIngredientText = $(this).text();
                    $("#IngredientName"+String(theIngredient)).val(selectedIngredientText);//THIS IS WHAT SETS EVERYTHING WITH AN ID OF IngredientNameX
                    $("#Ingredient"+String(theIngredient)+"ID").val(selectedIngredientID);
                    $("#Ingredients").addClass("hidden");
                });
                $("#Ingredients *").filter(function() {
                  $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            } else {
                $("#Ingredients").addClass("hidden")
            }
        });
        $("#AddIngredient").click(function(){
            var ingredientCounter = $("#ingredientCounter").val();
            ingredientCounter++;
            $("#ingredientCounter").val(ingredientCounter);
            $('#ingredientsContainer').append('\
                        <div class="ingredientsRowContainer">\
                            <div class="ingredientsInputContainer"><input class="effect-1 ingredientsInput" type="text" name="IngredientName'+ingredientCounter+'" placeholder="Ingredient" id="IngredientName'+ingredientCounter+'" data-ingID="'+ingredientCounter+'"><span class="focus-border"></span></div>\
                        </div>\
                        <input type="hidden" name="Ingredient'+ingredientCounter+'ID" id="Ingredient'+ingredientCounter+'ID">\
            ');

        });

    });

    </script>
```

[UPDATE] I realized the problem is happening because the function is running multiple times.  I assume this happening because I'm calling a function on keyup of a field whose id starts with IngredientName so when one has a key up event, all existing fields run the function.  How do i modify my:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', "[id^=IngredientName]",function () {
```

to only run on the field with focus?

Comment: Change this $(document).on('keyup', "[id^=IngredientName]",function () {  });  to this $('#IngredientName').on('keyup',function() {  });

Comment: would you please provide the complete code ? .Ingredients div part and the css

Comment: @RohanRao that won't work as the input fields have ID's of IngredientName1, IngredientName2, etc.  that's why i was using the wildcard .on('keyup')

Comment: Can't you write class instead of giving IDs and then write this jquery function?